# Timing out or taking forever? RE: Journey Audience Filter

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, filters

I have a Data Extension called [Users] that is 3.4MM records.

I am applying filters from linked data extensions.  The result should be about  4,300 records (as pulled from a query).

When I test the journey - it doesn't provide any results for 'Contacts Evaluated'.  When I look in the automation studio, I only show that the automation is running, but no progress.

The question is: does it take a long time to evaluate all those records (pushing 6 hours now) or has this process timed out?

Comment: Believe you might need to raise a case with support - if you have multiple links on multiple DE's, it can be a real challenge with the processing - plus, but this might only be in journey builder, it will always choose the shortest path, which might "ruin" your intended logic.

Comment: Still waiting for a reply from support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volume was too high, according to support.
MC times out when you get into the million(s).

The rep said that, as a rule, your filter should only cut your population by about 50-60%.